# jQuery - Duplicating a bit of HTML when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to replicate a block of HTML directly under the other one.

I have a table, with a 'add row' button underneath it, when a user clicks the 'add row' button, i need it to replicate the following HTML

```
<tr style="height: 31px;">
<td style="background-color: #e4e4e4;">
    <select name="timetocall" id="timetocall" style="width: 159px; margin-left: 8px;">
        <option value="residential" selected>Residential</option>
    </select>       
</td>
<td style="background-color: #e4e4e4;">$ <input type="text" value="120,000.00" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" style="width: 151px;" maxlength="256"></td>
<td style="background-color: #e4e4e4;">$ <input type="text" value="420,000.00" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" style="width: 151px;" maxlength="256"></td>
</tr>
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `<tr>` an ID, e.g. `id="template"`, then:

```
$('#template').clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('table > tbody');
```

You might also want to replace any IDs that will be cloned, such as `id="timetocall"` and replace them with classes, since all IDs should be unique.

---

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EGp6Q/.

Comment: Will that be able to keep replicating? ... if i click the 'add row' button twice, will it clone the html twice?